# How to automatically disable a button when time is up

Tags: ios, swift4

```
@IBAction func BtnClickMe(sender: UIButton) {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.CLOCK), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
```

Here is my clock function when timer is running, stop clock when it reach 0 sec.

```
@objc func CLOCK(){
    sec = sec - 1
    lbnTime.text = "\(sec)"
    if(sec == 0){
        lbnTime.text = "Time Up"
        timer.invalidate()
        //disable button here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the button as IBOutlet property

and disable it with: `button.isEnabled = false`

Comment: Thanks for your help!